# Limit of the following integration

Tags: limits

Let $F$ and $G$ be a CDF with a support [0,1], strictly increasing and with finite pdf's.

What should be the limit of the following integration as $n$ approaches to $\infty$?

$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_0F^{n}(x+\frac{1}{2})dG(x)$$
My intuition tells me that the value should be zero because $F^n$ in the limit converges to a step function whose value is zero everywhere and 1 at $x=1$.

How can I prove that it indeed converges to zero?

Answer (score 1):

We have that $F^n(x+\frac{1}{2})\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}F^n(x+\frac{1}{2})dG(x)=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}F^n(x+\frac{1}{2})\frac{dG(x)}{dx}dx=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}F^n(x+\frac{1}{2})g(x)dx$$
where $g$ is the pdf for the cdf $G$

As $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ is compact and in particular closed, then $g$ is bounded on $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ as $g$ is finite  (This is quite wavy so feel free to correct me)

Also, $F^n(x)\leq1$ hence by DCT we get

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}F^n(x+\frac{1}{2})dG(x) \rightarrow 0$$

Comment: Thanks, asdf. What does DCT stand for?